# How to call method in jar file with terminal?

Tags: java, linux, jar, terminal

I have a compiled project in a jar file and I need to call a method from it.How can I do that in ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can not call any method from terminal or cmd of any class.

You can execute class through terminal.

If your `jar` is executable try:  `java -jar "Name of your Jar"`

Or set the class path of your jar:  `java -classpath path-to-jar <package>.<classname>`

Comment: We can give the method name as parameter. If it is public, it will run. 
java -jar <Jar name> <Method Name>. It executes all the methods with the same name across all the packages in the jar.

Comment: How doe you call the method though?

Answer (score 7):

```
java -cp path/to/jar <package>.<classname>
```

example:

```
java -cp test.jar org.dekz.HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 4):

> I need to call a method from it.

This is not very specific statement. if you are interested to call main method of your Main class then you can do

```
java -jar path/to/yourjar/yourJar.jar
```

- [JAR Basics](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/)

if you want to call a method from this class from another class then you need to add this jar into your classpath and then you can access other methods. but since you wrote from terminal I assume the first approach fits for you

Answer (score -1):

you can call a specific method from a jar file if and only if the developer programmed the file to call it from outside. You can use a jar explorer to fine the details of each class inside a jar file