# Interacting with Java Jar through Command Line

Tags: java

What are some ways to interact with a `jar` post creation in the command line? I know you can pass parameters when it's created (e.g. java -jar foo.jar foo bar) but this isn't what I want.

Example of what I would like to happen

```
java -jar foo.jar
```

Some time later

```
// Someway to interact with the above jar e.g. Call a method
```

Comment: What type of interaction are you referring to?

Comment: Any way you could possibly image. And more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call method in jar file with terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950538/how-to-call-method-in-jar-file-with-terminal)

Comment: I would like to call a method and pass parameters to the method via command line.

Comment: @GregWringle why? Why focus on methods? This exposes far too much of the internals of the application to the end user. Look into, for example, JMX. Or you could go the whole way and use an HTTP server and REST (for another example).

Comment: It's the first thing that came to mind. I guess what I really want is to pass a jar a set of parameters and have it do something with them after the jar has been started.

Comment: Who not do _exactly that_ `java -jar myJar.jar --do-some-magic-stuff` for example?

Comment: That does it once and I would like to pass different parameters at a later time and maybe multiple times.

I'm getting the feeling this is difficult for Java and I might be better off with C++.

Comment: you want to execute multiple times ? (add a parameter for that), or you want to give input after it starts ? (then use console and System.in)

Comment: I want to give input after it starts and have it do something with that input. Correct me if I'm wrong but System.in only works for the terminal that it's in correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "String args\[\]"? parameter in main method Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

Comment: All the uses with

    public static void main(String args[])

args is once the jar is created, no?

Comment: It is no different in Java than in C++ or any other language. You first need to define what exactly the interaction is, then you need to implement it.

Comment: Ok what I want is to create a system where there is a central processor that works on tasks. Tasks would be sent to the central processor at random, in both amount and time sent.

e.g. 
- Central Processor start
- Task 0 comes at time 0
- Task 1 comes at time 1
- Task 2 comes at time 6
- Task 3 comes at time 6
- Task 4 comes at time 10

Comment: The user decides when to launch tasks ? then you can use my code (and testing what is on input), or is it configured somewhere ? then you need a scheduler : there exists  libraries for that.

Comment: Yes the user will decide when to launch a task for the processor to work on. The flow would be something like this. Processor starts up. A task is received and processor works on the task. If any task is received when the processor is busy, add it to a queue.

For your code would it only work for the terminal that the jar was created in?

Comment: the console (System.in) is where you start the jar. You definitively need to do some parallel tasks, then you have to use threads at minimum (or other processes, ...) the main process read from console, and launch others tasks.

Comment: @GregWringle none of that really answers the big questions. 1) **what** is a task and 2) **how** is a task sent.

Comment: A task would be to run through automated tasks, taking in file location, device name, device type.
Ideally a task would be sent through command line to the jar. (After the jar has been started)

Note: Ideally the Java program would be a command line program.

Comment: Then you should reformulate your question or post a new one, and close this one:  "What are some ways to interact with a jar post creation in the command line?"

Answer (score 0):

A typical method to interact with a jar file is to specify the main class to be called, and then read the arguments from command line.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
   // evaluate command line arguments here
   System.out.println("number of arguments=" + args.length);
   System.out.println("arg1" + args[0]);
}
```

On command line:

```
java.exe -cp myjar.jar com.mycompany.Myclass  arg1 arg2 arg3
```

where MyClass contains the main method.

Answer (score 0):

see: [What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

```
 public static void main(String args[])
{
int n=args.length; // number of arguments

String arg1=args[0]; // param 1
// then param2, ...

}
```

Interacting during the program:

see this: [How to use readline() method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560395/how-to-use-readline-in-java)

```
    BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line=buffer.readLine();
    System.out.println("LINE:"+line);
```

If you want to run some task, and in the same time, get some user input, you have to launche yours tasks with a thread: see this for example: [Java - creating a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758411/java-creating-a-new-thread)